# Is the product of a continuously differentiable function with a test function also a test function?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I have $\phi(x)\sin(nx)$ where $\phi(x)$ is a test function. Obviously, the product is continuously differentiable, but I don't know if $\phi(x)\sin(nx)$ has a compact support too?

Comment: If $\phi$ has compact support, then so does the product.

Comment: $\phi(x) = 0 \implies \phi(x)\,\sin(nx) = 0$, right ? Did you at least try to prove it ?

Comment: thanks, I did but I wasn't sure about it.